# variable and array based on line of text

Tags: string, powershell, variables

The file i am trying to read looks like example below

```
variable, arrElement1, arrElement2, arrElemen3, arrelement[n]...
variable, arrElement1, arrElement2, arrElemen3, arrelement[n]...
.
.
.
variable, arrElement1, arrElement2, arrElemen3, arrelement[n]...
```

what i am trying to achieve is to read this file and assign "variable" as one element variable
and arrElement's as array of elements

something like that:

:PseudoCode:

```
foreach (line in text file)
   $variable=variable
   $array = "arrElement1", "arrElement2", "arrElement3", ....
   foreach( $element in $array) {
      'do some stuff'
   }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```psh
Get-Content 'C:\your.txt' | % {
  $arr = $_ -split '\s*,\s*'
  New-Variable -Name $arr[0] -Value $arr[1..$arr.Length]
}
```

**Edit:** According to your pseudo code you meant to keep the first field in one variable and the rest of the fields as an array in the second variable. That's even simpler to achieve:

```psh
Get-Content 'C:\your.txt' | % {
  $var, $arr = $_ -split '\s*,\s*'
  $arr | % {
    # do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that looks quiet simple. On the beginning i was thinking about creating array with all elements and do for loop (starting from 2nd element in array).

@Walter could you please comment one line of your code. I am not sure about what is really going on there.

   $var, $arr = $_ -split '\s*,\s*'

looks like regex to me .. can't it be just ','  ?

Thank you

Comment: @hermitagup The name's Ansgar, not Walter. Yes, you could also use `-split ','` instead of `-split '\s*,\s*'`. However, if you do that, the array values will retain all whitespace that was before/after the commas. For instance, splitting a string `"a , b"` like that would produce an array with the 2 strings `"a "` (with a trailing space) and `" b"` (with a leading space). The `\s*` in the splitting regexp prevent that.

Comment: @Ansgar, truly sorry about that mistake. Thank you for explaining me that part. I totally agree with your clever solution. Have a nice code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: its better here to use `[ ]*` (ascii space only) instead to `\s*` (all unicode whitespace): to speed performance and to avoid matching `\n` or `\f` ...etc , or an other solution is to avoid using `\s*` and use `Trim()`

Comment: @walidtoumi You'd need pretty large files for this to become a performance issue. A quick test with an input file of 1 million lines and 8 fields per line didn't show any significant difference between splitting at `\s*,\s*` and `,` (1:25 each). Reading the data from disk takes significantly longer than that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: yes the difference is with big data, because .NET engine try all kind of whitspace with `\s` instead of `[ ]*`